# Copy by clicking on the text and also the button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I can copy the text from table cell right after clicking on it but I'm unable to copy the text after clicking on the button. Any ideas how can I fix that kind of problem. I think that problem might be in js this line `const el = document.createElement('textarea');` but I'm not sure.
https://codepen.io/S4UCY/pen/abNpyWB

```js
/* Copy after clicking on text */
document.querySelectorAll(".table-cell").forEach(function(elm){
elm.addEventListener("click", function(e){
 e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'green'; 
  var copyText = e.target.textContent; 
   const el = document.createElement('textarea');
  el.value = copyText;
  document.body.appendChild(el);
  el.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  document.body.removeChild(el);

 
  /* Alert the copied text */
  alert("Copied the text: " + el.value);
  
});

})



function myFunction() {
  /* Get the text field */
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");

  /* Select the text field */
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /*For mobile devices*/

  /* Copy the text inside the text field */
  document.execCommand("copy");

  /* Alert the copied text */
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
```

```css
td button{
    float: right;
}

td button:before {
  content: "Copy";
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="table-cell" id="myInput" scope="row">kaching<button onclick="myFunction()" type="button" name="button"></button></td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table-cell">Jacob </td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table-cell">Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the button is a child of the `<li>`, how about just having the button not do anything and let the click event propagate up to the `<li>`, and let its listener handle everything?

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".table-cell").forEach(function(elm) {
  elm.addEventListener("click", copyText);
})

function copyText(e) {
  const td = e.currentTarget;
  td.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  var copyText = td.textContent;
  const el = document.createElement('textarea');
  el.value = copyText;
  document.body.appendChild(el);
  el.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  document.body.removeChild(el);


  /* Alert the copied text */
  alert("Copied the text: " + el.value);
}
```

```css
td button {
  float: right;
}

td button:before {
  content: "Copy";
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="table-cell" id="myInput" scope="row">kaching<button type="button" name="button"></button></td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table-cell">Jacob </td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table-cell">Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because when you click on the button, you are trying to copy its own text instead of the table cell.

```js
elm.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'green'; 
    var copyText = e.target.textContent; // when the button is clicked, "e" is the button
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i came up with a different approach to your issue on hand. What i did was remove the direct call `onclick="myFunction()"` and implement a tag validation inside the `eventListener` to check whether the element was a button and then instead of calling `myFunction()`, which is now deprecated, I just did the process to gather the value there. Which in return also avoided duplicated lines of code.

```js
/* Copy after clicking on text */
document.querySelectorAll(".table-cell").forEach(function(elm){
elm.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  var copyText;
  if(e.target.tagName == "BUTTON") { // <----- Validation
    /* Get the text field by searching for the cell */
    var elem = document.getElementById("myInput");
    elem.style.backgroundColor = 'green'; 
    copyText = elem.textContent;
  } else {
    /* Get the text field directly */
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'green'; 
    copyText = e.target.textContent;
  }
  
  const el = document.createElement('textarea');
  el.value = copyText;
  document.body.appendChild(el);

  /* Select the text field */
  el.select();
  el.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /*For mobile devices*/

  /* Copy the text inside the text field */
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.body.removeChild(el);

  /* Alert the copied text */
  alert("Copied the text: " + el.value);
});

})

function myFunction() {} // <------ Removed
```

```css
td button{
    float: right;
}

td button:before {
  content: "Copy";
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="table-cell" id="myInput" scope="row">kaching<button type="button" name="button"></button></td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table-cell">Jacob </td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table-cell">Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the reason of the error

```js
elm.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'green'; 
    var copyText = e.target.textContent; // when the button is clicked, "e" is the button
   ...
}
```